# Creating a Backup of AWS account configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, snapshot, disaster-recovery

I would like to create a Backup of my whole AWS account. I don't have a proper IaaS setup - did almost all of configurations manually using the AWS console. For now I am looking for a solution that just snapshots all my AWS services configurations (content is optional or could be done successively via scripts).

My setup includes:

- Compute-Instances
- Database aaS (DynamoDB)
- Identity and Access Control Configs
- SaaS, e.g. Lambda, configured manually
- DNS configurations (Route53 and CertificateManager)
- S3 Storage
- CDN configurations

As a result I would like to have something like a CloudFormation Script that I can use to recreate my accounts configuration in a new AWS account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AWS CloudFormer to create a Cloudformation template out of the existing resources and create a Cloudformation Stack with that template in the another account. Refer to the link -->
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

Comment: That helped, thanks! However, some newer services are not supported by CloudFormer.